# popBackStack() not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

When I open a fragment from BottomNavigationBar, it opens perfectly. When I press back button, previous fragment opens but state of BottomNavigationBar does not change.

As in my screenshots, when i backpressed from Account fragment, Home fragment opens but state of BottomNavigationBar has not been changed.

Screenshot 1 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/12cDvhwO1jpG2A1PUsfHQGProqx2cT6Bp/view

Screenshot 2 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zws5sMJeXxts6k6IEBGUGyJYfZP58Czs/view

```
 btnNavBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_item1:
                   loadFragment(fragmentManager, new HomeFragment(), "Home");
                    break;

                case R.id.action_item2:
                        loadFragment(fragmentManager, new SearchFragment(), "Search");
                     break;

                case R.id.action_item3:
                   loadFragment(fragmentManager, new AccountFragment(), "Account");
                    break;


            }
            return true;
        }
    });

 public static void loadFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Fragment fragment, String tag) {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutContainer, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: post your implementation

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to not add the fragments to the back stack because it's not the expected behaviour for the Android users. The bottom bar is here to show 3 to 5 different destinations to the user (for example, a news feed, a user profile, etc.). When you select a tab, you should just change the current fragment (and not create a fragments stack). The back button should only close the app, or re-open the previous screen if there is one (definitely not re-open the previous tab :) ). I suggest you to look at this [Material Design guidelines](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html) for BottomNavigationBar.